# Can anyone explain this command?

Tags: excel

=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("gut";D23;1));IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("schlecht";D23;1));"Nicht vorhanden";"schlecht");"gut")

What exactly does the "ISERROR", and why is only "gut" shown, if in the text is "gut" and "schlecht"?

Tried to look up but didnt found answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to add some indenting in order to understand your formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("gut";D23;1));
    IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("schlecht";D23;1));
       "Nicht vorhanden";
       "schlecht");
    "gut")
```

You need to realise that `SEARCH("something";some_text;1)` can result in either:

- the first occurrence of "something" inside your text, or:
- an error

So your formula means:

```
IF D23 does not contain "gut"
THEN IF D23 does not contain "schlecht"
     THEN "Nicht vorhanden"              // no "gut" and no "schlecht"
     ELSE "schlecht"                     // no "gut" but "schlecht"
     END IF
ELSE "gut"                               // "gut"
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

> [IsError](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/iserror-function-40a89200-138b-4e60-b254-34aea51b2e6b) returns True if the expression argument indicates an error; otherwise, it returns False.